# Generalization of Pompeiu's theorem

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, trigonometric-sums

Let us recall the statement of

**Pompeiu's theorem.** *Let  $A_1A_2A_3$ be a regular triangle inscribed in a circle $\omega$. Let $X$ be an arbitrary point on the arc $A_1A_3$. Then $$|XA_1|-|XA_2|+|XA_3|=0.$$*

Do you know the following generalization?

**Generalized Pompeiu's theorem.** Let $n$ be an odd number and  $A_1A_2 \ldots A_n$ be a regular polygon inscribed in a circle $\omega$. Let $X$ be an arbitrary point on the arc $A_1A_n$. Then for each odd $k=1,3,\ldots, n-2$ $$|XA_1|^k-|XA_2|^k+|XA_3|^k-\ldots +|XA_n|^k = 0.$$

[image]
**Remark 1.** Case $k=1$ is known (http://www.mathnet.ru/links/c180be9985fb3bc9375b57f527b8cab9/kvant560.pdf , in russian).

**Remark 2.** If $n$ is even, then for an arbitrary point $X$ in the plane (not necessary on $\omega$) and each even $k=2,4,\ldots, n-2$ $$|XA_1|^k-|XA_2|^k+|XA_3|^k-\ldots -|XA_n|^k = 0.$$
It follows from the following result https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.10406.pdf

**Remark 3.** Using law of sines this theorem can be reformulated as some trigonometric identity. Maybe this identity is known.

**UPDATE** Fedor Baharev found an article with this result https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00151582

Comment: Does $XA_i^k$ here denote the $k$-th power of the length of the segment $XA_i$? The notation is not terribly clear...

Comment: @Wojowu Yes. I added vertical bars.

Comment: (Re: Remark 1.) The case $k=1$ was well-known long before  Bakaev's paper. E.g. Шклярский, Ченцов, Яглом. Избранные задачи и теоремы элементарной математики, Ч. 2: Геометрия (планиметрия), 1952. — № 118, с. 37.

Comment: @GrigoryM Thank you for the reference.

Comment: I did not know, but a standard proof works: if $a_i$ are roots of unity, then $\sum (x-a_i)^k a_i^{k(n-1)/2}=0$ for any $x$ (expand the brackets and realize that $a_i$ never comes in a power divisible by $n$, so everything cancels out), it remains to check the arguments to see that it is $\sum (-1)^i |x-a_i|^k$ up to a constant factor

Comment: copy of Fedor Bakharev's comment: "Мне кажется, задача в стиле "Для каких k верно?" Была на какой-то из американских олимпиад... надо поискать на aops'e." [I remember that the question "for which $k$ is it ture that...?" was on some American olympiad, should be searched on AoPS]

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thank you! Is it standard? What are other applications of this technique? Unfortunately, I have not found this problem on AoPS.

Comment: @FedorNilov for example, for any cyclic $2n$-gon the alternating sum of reciprocals of products $\prod_{j:j\ne i} A_j A_i$ equals 0.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks!